# Scrollwheel not working in Chrome for OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, jsf, retina-display

I have an application built with JSF and PrimeFaces.  I am using a layoutPane and within it are two panels.  I have set up CSS to scroll the content sections of the panels however the scrollwheel will not work on OSX using Chrome version 51.  I can however use the arrow keys to scroll the section.  The scrolling works as expected when using Safari and Firefox but not Chrome.

I should note also that I am using a Mac Pro with Retina display.  I also have a second monitor attached that is a HP w2207.  To make things even more interesting, if I drag the Chrome window to the HP monitor the scrolling works as expected.  Dragging the window back to the laptop Retina display and the scrolling no longer works.

I have tried various system settings and nothing has worked.  I have also tried altering the HTML/CSS thinking maybe there is some kind of collision between the parent panel and the child panels but I have not been able to come up with a fix.

Has anyone experienced this issue before or could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Chrome to version 52.

I'm working on a different stack, but the issue seems to be exactly the same: in some cases scroll doesn't work and it happens only when I'm using Chrome 51 and Retina. I wasn't able to find the cause, and the only solution that I know is upgrading Chrome.

Comment: Very odd bug and glad it was Chrome related.  I suspected that was the issue but it seems rather odd Google would have some sort of display specific logic that would cause the bug.  Would love to see the changelog of this fix.